# Set last scroll position to UITextView before view appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout, uitextview

Right now, I have `UITextView` in `BViewController`. I save it's scroll position to `AViewController` when viewWillDisappear with

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    double d = self.textView.contentOffset.y;
    self.aViewController.lastOffset = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:d];

    NSLog(@"textView contentHeight %f", self.textView.contentSize.height)
}
```

When user comes back to `BViewController`, I set `UITextView` to last scroll position.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Force layout
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    [self.textView.layoutManager ensureLayoutForTextContainer:self.textView.textContainer];
    //[self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    double d = [self.aViewController.lastOffset doubleValue];
    [self.textView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, d) animated:NO];

    NSLog(@"textView contentHeight %f", self.textView.contentSize.height);
}
```

The result is, `UITextView`'s scroll position is off from the last scroll position. `NSLog` value in `viewWillAppear` is way less than in `viewWillDisappear`. Even though I forced it to layout with `ensureLayoutForTextContainer` or `layoutIfNeeded`.

I know I get correct result in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, but the user will be able to see it animating to the last scroll position.

Is it not possible to set subview's scroll position before view appears?

Thanks in advance.